# Check if logged in before doing action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, retrofit

My app has some `onClick()` events, some of which should require a login for the request to be sent.

How should I handle what happens if someone clicks on something that requires them to be logged in for the action to happen?

I have the following Retrofit class:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static ApiEndpointInterface apiService;
    private static String API_URL = "http://www.website.com/api";

    private RestClient() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);
    }

    public static ApiEndpointInterface getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }

    public class SessionRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            if (PreferenceUtils.isLoggedIn()) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", PreferenceUtils.getTokenId() + ":" + PreferenceUtils.getTokenKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's called elsewhere like this:

```
RestClient.getApiService().getUser(new Callback<UserData>() {
    @Override
    public void success(UserData json, Response response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

    }
});
```

As you can see, the interceptor adds an `Authorization` header if they're logged in, but should I prevent the call from being made altogether if they're not logged in? How should I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("some_name",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

after the login

```
sp.edit().putBoolean("logged", true).commit();
```

anfd next time you can check if the user is already looged in or not

```
if (sp.getBoolean("logged", false)) {

  //LOGGED IN, DO YOUR CODE

 }
else{
  //NOT LOGGED IN
 }
```